# Hash map does not add elements properly

Tags: java, javafx, hashmap

I am trying to make a line chart that indicates the election votes for some parties. I tried to do this using `Map<String,Map<Integer,Double>>` the string represents the name of the party and the double and integer represent the percentage and year in which it was obtained. My solution was to make another map`Map<Integer,Double>>` that I can then the use to add elements to my first map, the small map gets correctly created, but when when added to the big one it does not make it in correctly

```java
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.chart.LineChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.io.IOException;

public class mainMethod extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
        Map < String, Map < Integer, Double >> parties = new LinkedHashMap < > ();

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        String filename = "C://Users//rares//IdeaProjects//DataVizualization//src//main//java//partiesdata.tsv";

        File file = new File(filename);
        Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file);

        Map < Integer, Double > helpMap = new LinkedHashMap < > ();
        Integer c = 0;
        Integer year = 1968;
        while (inputFile.hasNext()) {

            String partySupport = inputFile.nextLine();
            String[] split = partySupport.split("   ");
            c++;

            if (c > 1) {
                helpMap.clear();
                year = 1964;
                for (int i = 1; i < split.length; i++) {
                    year = year + 4;
                    if (!(split[i].equals("-"))) {

                        helpMap.put(year, Double.valueOf(split[i]));

                        //                        System.out.println("year: "+year +" percetange: "+ Double.valueOf(split[i]));
                    }
                }
                parties.put(split[0], helpMap);
                System.out.println(helpMap);
            }
        }

        inputFile.close();
        keyboard.close();
        System.out.println(parties);

        NumberAxis xAxis = new NumberAxis(1968, 2008, 4);
        NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis(0, 30, 4);

        LineChart < Number, Number > lineChart = new LineChart < > (xAxis, yAxis);
        lineChart.setTitle("Relative support of the parties");

        parties.keySet().stream().forEach(party -> {
            XYChart.Series data = new XYChart.Series();
            data.setName(party);
            parties.get(party).entrySet().stream().forEach(pair -> {
                data.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(pair.getKey(), pair.getValue()));

            });
            lineChart.getData().add(data);
        });

        Scene view = new Scene(lineChart, 640, 480);
        stage.setScene(view);
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

file used

```
Party   1968   1972   1976   1980   1984   1988   1992   1996   2000   2004   2008
KOK   16.1   18.1   20.9   22.9   23.0   22.9   19.1   21.6   20.8   21.8   23.4
SDP   23.9   27.1   24.8   25.5   24.7   25.2   27.1   24.5   23.0   24.1   21.2
KESK   18.9   18.0   18.4   18.7   20.2   21.1   19.2   21.8   23.8   22.8   20.1
VIHR   -   -   -   -   2.8   2.3   6.9   6.3   7.7   7.4   8.9
VAS   16.9   17.5   18.5   16.6   13.1   12.6   11.7   10.4   9.9   9.6   8.8
PS   7.3   5.0   2.1   3.0   5.3   3.6   2.4   0.9   0.7   0.9   5.4
RKP   5.6   5.2   4.7   4.7   5.1   5.3   5.0   5.4   5.1   5.2   4.7
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>DataVizualization</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <release>11</release>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.5</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>mainMethod</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <!--Shader-->
            <!--            <plugin>-->
            <!--                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>-->
            <!--                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>-->
            <!--                <version>3.0.0</version>-->
            <!--                <executions>-->
            <!--                    <execution>-->
            <!--                        <phase>package</phase>-->
            <!--                        <goals>-->
            <!--                            <goal>shade</goal>-->
            <!--                        </goals>-->
            <!--                        <configuration>-->
            <!--                            <createDependencyReducedPom>false</createDependencyReducedPom>-->
            <!--                        </configuration>-->
            <!--                    </execution>-->
            <!--                </executions>-->
            <!--            </plugin>-->

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>mainMethod</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>15.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>15.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.jfoenix/jfoenix -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jfoenix</groupId>
            <artifactId>jfoenix</artifactId>
            <version>9.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.20</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>RELEASE</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>RELEASE</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>RELEASE</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>RELEASE</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>RELEASE</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.197</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>


</project>
```

I used those two prints there to show the problem better, I have never encountered this before when using hashmaps. Also I used linked hashmaps because when I tried to add elements to the smaller map the order was getting messed up and this was the only solution i found.

Comment: What exactly do you expect `helpMap.clear()` to do?

Comment: well, after it is added to parties I want to start with a clean map so I can add the next one without having any other data in it

Comment: Okay, but what do you expect to happen to the map that you added to `parties` when you clear it?

Comment: You're adding the same map every time.

Comment: @James_D and where should I add it so that I add each map once?

Comment: You need to create a new map each time, instead of just creating one.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- well I thought that it gets cleared and I can just add another one after, I didn't think it got deleted from `parties` if I clear it(I'm guessing that s what is happening I am still not sure why the code does not work)

Comment: Yes. _It gets cleared_. It doesn't get deleted from `parties`, but _you only have one map_.

Comment: Again: *you only create one `Map<Integer,Double>`*. There is only one map. You add the same map repeatedly to `parties` and clear the same map repeatedly. All party names in `parties` map to the same `Map<Integer,Double>` as their value.

Comment: @James_D
 I get it, I should create another instance each time, not clear the old one, thanks.

Comment: Probably this is not a particularly good approach anyway. Why not do the obvious thing: create a `VotingResult` class with `int year` and `double voteShare` fields and then a `PartyResults` class with `String name` and `List<VotingResult>` fields, and then just build a `List<PartyResults>`? If you are using Java 16 or later, you could use records instead of classes.